# $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i+1} \text{ subject to the condition } \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization

To minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i+1} \text{ subject to the condition } \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i = p$$ for some fixed $p$. How can we proceed with the problem?

Comment: Whats wrong with constructing a Lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You do require that $x_i \geq -1$. Otherwise, take $ x_1 \rightarrow -1^{-}$, which doesn't have a lower bound.

Approach 1: [Titu's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/)

> Applying it directly tells us that
>  $$ \sum \frac{1}{x_i+1} \geq  \frac{ n^2 } { p+n}$$
>  Now show that equality can occur.

---

Approach 2: Jensen's. This is immediate once you verify that the conditions are satisfied.